# Ошибка Python Pandas - The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

Жестко затупил на контрольном задании на курсе ЯндексПрактикум "Аналитик данных"

Дана таблица:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('/datasets/music_project.csv')
```

***Задание:***

**Утро понедельника и вечер пятницы — разная музыка или одна и та же?**

Ищем ответ на вопрос, какие жанры преобладают в разных городах в понедельник утром и в пятницу вечером. Есть предположение, что в понедельник утром пользователи слушают больше бодрящей музыки (например, жанра поп), а вечером пятницы — больше танцевальных (например, электронику).

Получим таблицы данных по Москве moscow_general и по Санкт-Петербургу spb_general.

```py
# получение таблицы moscow_general из тех строк таблицы df, 
# для которых значение в столбце 'city' равно 'Moscow'
moscow_general = df[df['city'] == 'Moscow']
```

```py
# получение таблицы spb_general
# для которых значение в столбце 'city' равно 'Saint-Petersbur'
spb_general = df[df['city'] == 'Saint-Petersburg']
```

```py
Создаём функцию genre_weekday(), которая возвращает список жанров по запрошенному дню недели и времени суток с такого-то часа по такой-то.

def genre_weekday(df, day, time1, time2):
    genre_list =  df[ (df['weekday'] == day) & (df['time']>time1) & (time2>df['time'])]
    genre_list_sorted = genre_list.groupby('genre_name')['genre_name'].count().sort_values(ascending = False).head(10) 
    return genre_list_sorted

# объявление функции genre_weekday() с параметрами df, day, time1, time2

# в переменной genre_list сохраняются те строки df, для которых одновременно:
# 1) значение в столбце 'weekday' равно параметру day,
# 2) значение в столбце 'time' больше time1 и
# 3) меньше time2.

# в переменной genre_list_sorted сохраняются в порядке убывания  
# первые 10 значений Series, полученной подсчётом числа значений 'genre_name'
# сгруппированной по столбцу 'genre_name' таблицы genre_list

# функция возвращает значение genre_list_sorted
```

Cравниваем полученные результаты по таблице для Москвы и Санкт-Петербурга в понедельник утром (с 7 до 11) и в пятницу вечером (с 17 до 23).

**Утро понедельника в Москве**

```py
# <вызов функции для утра понедельника в Москве (вместо df таблица moscow_general)>
genre_weekday(moscow_general, 'Monday', '07:00:00', '11:00:00')
```

**Результат:**

```
genre_name
pop            781
dance          549
electronic     480
rock           474
hiphop         286
ruspop         186
world          181
rusrap         175
alternative    164
classical      157
Name: genre_name, dtype: int64
```

**Утро понедельника в СПб**

```py
# <вызов функции для утра понедельника в Петербурге (вместо df таблица spb_general)>
genre_weekday(spb_general, 'Monday', '07:00:00', '11:00:00')
```

**Результат:**

```
genre_name
pop            218
dance          182
rock           162
electronic     147
hiphop          80
ruspop          64
alternative     58
rusrap          55
jazz            44
classical       40
Name: genre_name, dtype: int64
```

**Вечер пятницы в Москве**

```py
# <вызов функции для вечера пятницы в Москве>
genre_weekday(moscow_general, 'Friday', '17:00:00', '23:00:00')
```

**Результат:**

```
genre_name
pop            713
rock           517
dance          495
electronic     482
hiphop         273
world          208
ruspop         170
alternative    163
classical      163
rusrap         142
Name: genre_name, dtype: int64
```

**Вечер пятницы в СПб**

```py
# <вызов функции для вечера пятницы в Питере>
genre_weekday(spb_general, 'Friday', '17:00:00', '23:00:00')
```

**Результат:**

```
genre_name
pop            256
rock           216
electronic     216
dance          210
hiphop          97
alternative     63
jazz            61
classical       60
rusrap          59
world           54
Name: genre_name, dtype: int64
```

Популярные жанры в понедельник утром в Питере и Москве оказались похожи: везде, как и предполагалось, популярен поп. Несмотря на это, концовка топ-10 для двух городов различается: в Питере в топ-10 входит джаз и русский рэп, а в Москве жанр world.

В конце недели ситуация не меняется. Поп-музыка всё так же на первом месте. Опять разница заметна только в концовке топ-10, где в Питере пятничным вечером тоже присутствует жанр world

***Конец задания***

Вроде все сходится с написанными Яндексом подсказками и выводами, но при сдаче задания на проверку дает ошибку The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Суть ошибки вроде бы понял, но не понимаю в какой момент она возникает.

Если это может помочь, ссылка на диск со всеми заданиями. cell In [48]:
https://yadi.sk/d/xO0cm83NXVyPJA

Comment: В ссылке с данными у вас не хватает `csv` файла

Comment: В тренажере Яндекс не дает прямого доступа к csv файлу. Сделал свою небольшую выборку и перезалил.

Comment: я вот не смог воспроизвести ошибку на доступном мне датасете. Можете указать конкретный сниппет в ноутбуке, на который ругается интерпретатор? Судя по ошибке, вы где-то (я не нашел, где) используете неверные операторы (булевы) по отношению к серии. То есть, вместо булевых `and` и `or` нужно использовать поэлементные (element-wise) `&` и `|`.

Comment: Интерпретатор jupyter не ругается, но ошибку дает тренажер Яндекса и не пускает к следующим заданиям. [Скриншот](https://yadi.sk/i/I613NOEFPgLOfQ)

Сам пытался нагуглить причину ошибки и отыскать булевые операторы, но все тщетно. Скорее всего где-то закралась глупая ошибка, но не могу отловить, где она. Если вам удобно, могу предоставить доступ к сервису, наверное так будет проще.

[Ссылка на урок](https://praktikum.yandex.ru/trainer/data-analyst/lesson/cd601912-2c45-429c-b9f1-3ef16fb07a31/task/63e2c3f3-fa64-4376-8221-e8b753264535/)
Логин: tryastsinandrei
pass: LrF61GSpraktikum

Comment: К сожалению, под вашими данными я не зайду, да я и не советовал бы вам их публиковать, от греха подальше. Вероятно, вам нужно будет связаться с техподдержкой, чтобы уточнить, где именно возникает ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, проблема в этой строке:

```
genre_list =  df[ (df['weekday'] == day) & (df['time']>time1) & (time2>df['time'])]
```

Попробуйте заменить на какой-нибудь из этих вариантов:

```
genre_list = df.query('weekday == @day and @time2 > time > @time1')

genre_list = df.loc[(df['weekday'] == day) & (df['time'].between(time1, time2, inclusive=False))]
```

Answer (score 2):

У меня валидатор принял такой вариант:

```
genre_list = df[
   (df['weekday'] == day) & (df['time'] > time1) & (df['time'] < time2)]
```

возможно ему важно в каком порядке идут сравниваемые величины..